# jQuery date picker not working on ajax-generated input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input field that is generated via Ajax from the server-side, and inserted into the current page. My problem is: the jQuery date picker is not working on the input field when it is generated via Ajax, but it works when the field is directly placed in the page.

Below, I include a scaled-down version of my code.

HTML code:

```
<form id="user-form"></form>
```

And here's the jQuery code that's supposed to activate the datepicker on it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/inputfield-loader.php" ,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#user-form').html(data);
        $("#datefield").datepicker();
    } 
});
```

And here's `inputfield-loader.php`

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="birthdate" id="datefield"></div>
<div><input type="submit"></div>
```

As I already said, this works well if the input field is just hard-coded into the page. But when inserted into the DOM as the return string of an Ajax call, the date picker no longer works.

Anybody has any idea how to fix this?

**NOTE** I have updated the question to include codes showing exactly what is happening, as per the comment by @AkshayKhandelwal

Comment: execute the datepicker activation code after the ajax generation of the input field

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal, that's exactly what I'm doing and it isn't working

Comment: Javascript is no magic. It requires the element to bind events, unless the element is present you cannot add the callback on the event on that element

Comment: Since you add the element after the dom is loaded you can go only with delegated events in jquery using on(). If you don't manage to load datepicker with a delegated event you can add the input from start on the page, keep it hidden and show it when necessary

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal, I have updated my question with more code.

Comment: The first div around the input field seems not opened: `<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></div>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker not working on dynamic HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368314/jquery-datepicker-not-working-on-dynamic-html)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
success: function() {
  $('#datefield').datepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker no longer works, because you replace the existing with a new one. So the binding is not valid anymore, because the referenced datepicker doesn't exist.

You have to rebind the datepicker after inserting the new datepicker into the dom.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize the date picker in Ajax success, because you replace the existing with a newone.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "path" ,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $("#datefield").datepicker();
        } ,
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

Hope it's helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `$.ajax`, maybe you should do as below:

```
var _ajax = function(url, data, type){
    return $.ajax(url, {
        data: data
        type: type
    })
}
```

And use it as below:

```
_ajax('handler.ashx', null, 'POST').done(function(response){
    // this block of code will execute when `ajax request` is finished !
    // for you case:
    $('#datefield').datepicker();
 });
```